# Formula Field for Checking If a Custom Object's Related List in Account Record is Empty

Tags: formula, validation-rule

Aside from standard Account object, I have this custom object named `Object1__c`. This custom object contains a field that references the Account object named `Account__c`.

This is what I aim to achieve:

There must be an error message preventing the creation of Account record if Object1__c related list from Account record does not contain any records, and if `Picklist__c` from Account object is equal to this value: `Value1`.

I created a validation rule in Account object with this criteria:

```
AND(ISNULL($ObjectType.Account.Fields.Id),ISPICKVAL(Picklist__c,'Value1'))
```

There's no error when I check the syntax. But the problem is that it still saves the record when it's supposed not to be inserted to the database when the criteria above becomes true.

Comment: How can you create an Account record with a related Object1__c record? It has to be a two step process.  1. Create Account record  2. Create/Edit Object1__c record to lookup to Account record.

Comment: @NickCook let's assume that I have already previous records from both objects. I have three picklist values: Value1, Value2, and Value3. The app allows to create records having the first two picklist values. Only the last picklist value should prevent a record from being saved when there's no related Object1__c record to the Account record.

Comment: @curdual but by definition if the account is being created there will never ever be any object1__c records related to it as it does not exist yet. #confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible (or even logical) to achieve what you are asking. How can you have your `Object1__c` pointing to an `Account` record that has not been created yet? If you are inserting an `Account` record, the related list in your question will always be empty, since no `Ojbect1__c` record will be pointing to an `Account` record that doesn't even exists yet.

Aside to this, if you need to check if your `Account` record has any records in a related list, you have two options depending on the type of relationship between `Account` and `Object1__c`.

1) If you have a `Master-Detail` relationship between the `Account` and `Object1__c`, you need to create a `Roll-up Summary` field on your `Account` object that will `COUNT` the number of related `Object1__c` records. Then, in your validation rule you need to check the value of this `Roll-up Summary` field to see if it is 0.

2) If you have a `lookup` relationship between the `Account` and `Object1__c`, you can't use the `Roll-up Summary` field, but you can use a `trigger` that will perform the similar logic. You can run this trigger on `before update` to count the number of related `Object1__c` records and throw a validation error using the `addError(..)` method on [sObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

Also, as I mentioned at the beginning of my answer, note that this validation only makes sense on `Account` record update.

Comment: I have a lookup relationship between two objects. Can you show me how to get the related list count?

Comment: hey, I've followed your suggestion #2, and it is working now, thanks for your help.